# Files in Bucket no longer appear

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform, and while following the directions to install an SSL on a project, it appears the bucket for the project was wiped. No more files are showing up.

One, can anyone explain what I may have done wrong so I can avoid it in the future, and two, is there any server backups/undelete services that I can use to retrieve the files?

Comment: No idea. Installing SSL has **no** effect on objects stored in Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: I wouldn't think so either. Is there an activity log that may show when/how the files were removed?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging